# Mirroring Ports on a Cisco 3750 Stack

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-catalyst, mirror

We have a stack of 6, 48 port 3750 cisco switches and I would like to setup mirroring across the stack to send the data to a network analyser.   I have done mirroring before on a single switch, but never on a stack of swtiches.   My question is, what sort of things do I need to consider when trying to monitor a stack of c3750 switches with multiple vlans if I want to monitor all of the traffic on all VLANS with my network analyzer?

Since each switch is already stacked, do I only need to setup a single monitor port on one of the switches?

When I specify the port range that I want to monitor, should I just set the source port as being the various vlans I want to monitor, and then set the destination port as being a single port?

```
 switch 1 provision ws-c3750-48ts
 switch 2 provision ws-c3750-48ts
 switch 3 provision ws-c3750-48ts
 switch 4 provision ws-c3750-48ts
 switch 5 provision ws-c3750-48p
 switch 6 provision ws-c3750-48p
```

Sorry for asking multiple questions in a single post, I can break it up if needed - it just seems like all of the questions are a part of the overall question regarding configuring SPAN across a switch stack.

Comment: A switch stack is a single, logical device, with a single configuration, as if it were a chassis switch with multiple blades.

Comment: I figured so much, just wanted to check.   Regarding the configuration of mirroring multiple vlans on the stack to a single port, would the configuration be as I described it above?

Comment: A single port on one of the switches will work, except for the fact that a single port probably can't all the traffic for that many ports, and you will probably end up dropping a lot of traffic destined for that single port.

Comment: Yeah that could be an issue, but the network analyser is not mission critical  for us, we just want to get a better idea of the traffic on our LAN.    A few dropped packets would not be the end of the world.

Comment: Ron, if you want to make your comment into an answer id be happy to accept it.   BTW thank you for all you do for this site, I see you answer questions frequently and I always find your explanations to be of a very high quality.

Comment: You may want to investigate NetFlow for that sort of thing.

Comment: Do you mean instead of mirroring?   I am planning on using ntop to collect the traffic, which has the ability to capture netflow data.

Comment: OK, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch stack basically works like a single switch with a single configuration, much like a chassis switch with multiple blades.

You would configure SPAN the same way you do on a single switch. You can set up all the traffic to go to a single monitor port on any of the switches, although you could easily overload the single port and drop a lot of traffic.

For understanding your traffic mix and quantities, NetFlow may be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks Ron!  I will look into Netflow instead of mirroring

Comment: looks like netflow is not supported by the 3750s :(